# Selecting from div class dropdown - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an option from a drop-down that doesnt populate until the locator has been clicked. This is what I see in Firebug:

```
div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" placeholder="523-23-XXXXX" style="width: 109px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="selectize-dropdown multi form-control" style="display: none; width: 263px; top: 34px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="523-23-20273">523-23-20273</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="523-23-20274">523-23-20274</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="523-23-20275">523-23-20275</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="523-23-20276">523-23-20276</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="523-23-20280">523-23-20280</div>
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="523-23-202801">523-23-202801</div>
```

**The code I have so far is:**

```
public void selectAgentCodes(String agentCode)
    {
        driver.findElement(byAgentCodes).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("selectize-dropdown-content")));
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("selectize-dropwodn-content")));
        select.selectByVisibleText(agentCode);
    }
```

I get an **UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"**. I'm not sure how to handle this as I've only worked with selects before.

Lets say I wanted to select "523-23-20275" for the agent code. How would I go about this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a normal drop-down select menu. Hence, using `Select` won't work in this case. Without seeing the complete site, I'm not sure what exactly must be done to select it.

But try simply clicking on the `div` element when the options in the dropdown are visible.

```
//I'm assuming that this will display the dropdown list
driver.findElement(byAgentCodes).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-value='523-23-20275']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, Select class wouldn't work if there is no select tag in the UI, you need to click on the main div, and then you need to click on any of the div having multiple options, it will first click on the drop down and then click on the specific element from the list, 
below code will hopefully work for you....

1)firstly you need to click on this div by finding it through any of the available methods like by id, xpath, css selector, 
driver.findElement(byAgentCodes).click(); 
clicking on this will open a dropdown list

2) repeat the same above point 1 for clicking the any of list items in dropdown

523-23-20275

That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to select an item under div tag:

You have to use collections object to store all child elements which are stored under same tag.
For Ex if you have below HTML structure:

```
<div id="Year">
    <div class="abc">
         <ul class = "xyz">
             <li id=1>2000</li>
             <li id=2>2001</li>
             <li id=3>2002</li>
             <li id=4>2003</li>
             <li id=5>2004</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Write below selenium code:

```
List<Webelement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(<locator of child elements>));

//In this case it is //div[@id='Year']/div/ul/li
```

System will store all child elements in the list then you can select any element by index method using

```
lst.get(<index value>).click();
```

if you do not want to find using index but text use Iterator interface to find the element from the collection then click on that element:

```
Iterator<Webelement> it = lst.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    WebElement wb  = it.next();
    if(wb.getText().equals(<Text to find in double quotes>)) {
        wb.click();
        break;
    }

}
```