# How to get value from a list which is not a drop down in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div class="Select form-control undefined Select--single is-searchable has-value"><input name="deal.listdealasset[0].acacode" type="hidden" value="NEWCAR"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-3--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" id="react-select-3--value-item" role="option" aria-selected="true">New</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><style>input#undefined::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style><input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--value" aria-owns="" style="width: 19px; box-sizing: content-box;" value="" data-rxName="deal.listdealasset[0].acacode"><div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; overflow: scroll; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; white-space: pre; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></div></div></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div>
```

I'm trying to select a value from a drop-down but its html tag is not select.
I have tried various options but none work.

```
WebElement optionsList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'Select-multi-value-wrapper')]"));
List<WebElement> options = optionsList.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'Select-value-label')]"));
options.get(0).click();
```

I want to select the value new from drop down.[[image]]

I'm getting below error on execution -
Element  could not be scrolled into view

Below is the HTML code for the page-

```
<div class="Select form-control undefined Select--single is-searchable has-value">
   <input name="deal.listdealasset[0].acacode" type="hidden" value="NEWCAR">
   <div class="Select-control">
      <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-3--value">
         <div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" id="react-select-3--value-item" role="option" aria-selected="true">New</span></div>
         <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
            <style>input#undefined::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style>
            <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--value" aria-owns="" style="width: 19px; box-sizing: content-box;" value="" data-rxName="deal.listdealasset[0].acacode">
            <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; overflow: scroll; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; white-space: pre; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></div>
         </div>
      </span>
      <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting from div class dropdown - Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770848/selecting-from-div-class-dropdown-selenium)

Comment: tried with div but did not work

Comment: Can you share HTML code ? taking everything in a list of web element, and then try to click on one of the web element is the standard way to do it.

Comment: I have shared image of html code

Comment: Can you share that in plain text, It'd be easy for us to copy the HTML code and give you proper solution. and how many options are present in drop down anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your drop down is made of Div and span tags, **Select** class will not work from selenium.

Code you can try :

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(by.xpath(" your locator"));
for(WebElement element : options){
 if(element.getText().equals(" your value from drop down")){
    element.click();
}
}
```

Let me know, if you have any more concerns.

Comment: WebElement optionsList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'Select-multi-value-wrapper')]")); List<WebElement> options = optionsList.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'Select-value-label')]"));
      options.get(0).click();

Comment: I have tried with xpath as well but the value is still not selected

Comment: shared the html tag kindly let me know a solution for same...there are 2 values in drop down - New and Used

Comment: WebElement optionsList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'Select-multi-value-wrapper')]"));
      List<WebElement> options = optionsList.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'Select-value-label')]"));
     for(WebElement option : options) {
          if (option.getText().equals("New")) {          
           option.click();
          }
      } ...on executing above no error is displayed nor the value is getting selected

Comment: First you have to write the code to click on drop down, then only you can use my solution.

Comment: First write this : `driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-3--value")).click();`

Comment: then write xpath that selects both the values from drop down. Please share your XPATH for the options.

Answer (score 0):

Since You are getting error of element can not be scrolled into view. 
You should try JavascriptExecutor for scrolling.

1. This way will allow you to scroll horizontally/vertically page
   `((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,200)")` - only scroll vertically by 200 pixels

2 .  For bringing element into Focus

```
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: tried javascript - //JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'Select-value-label')]"));

  //je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);....but getting same cannot be scrolle dinto view error

Answer (score 0):

Since option 'new' had id attribute defined, clicking object is straight forward by using id.
Below code should work, provided that dropdown button is already clicked.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-3--value")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-3--value-item")).click();
```

Comment: This only clicks on the drop down , does not select the "New" value from list

Comment: Edit : I added code to click on new value in the list. Please try and let know.

Comment: I gives following error -Unable to locate element: #react\-select\-3\-\-value\-item

Comment: After lots of attempts - following code will type New in the drop down field - driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/section/div/from/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/span[1]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("New");

Comment: But still this is not allowing to use enter key as if we follow manual steps it normally would select "New"-driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[(@id='react-select-10--value')]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response .
It worked with below query i.e by merging send keys and keys.enter-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("react-select-3--value")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[2]/section/div/from/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/span[1]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("New",Keys.ENTER);
```